# How to setup concurrent request over the same DLL file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, dll

I have a core computation engine that is encapsulated into a DLL file.

There are two functions: **init** and **compute**. The former is called once to initialize the global variables of DLL (requires 4GB memory). The latter is called for each incoming request to perform the computation with the parameters in the request (global variables are never modified).

This engine is added into an IIS Website where it is expected to process many requests concurrently.

How can I run compute method concurrently?

Comment: There isn't much we can suggest without a [mcve].

Comment: At a high level, I would run `init` at application startup. And then call `compute` whenever you need it (likely in response to a web request). This will only work if `computer` is explicitly thread-safe.